# Android - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Notes/File.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, readfile, filenotfoundexception

I found lot of topics with the same problem, but they couldn't fix mine.
I initially write a file as follow:`

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }
    File notefile = new File(root, sFileName);
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(notefile);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        writer.append(sBody);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Don't worry about the try and catch blocks, i will clear them later :D.
And this is the reader which should works in the same directory ("Notes" of the sdcard, if it doesn't exist, will be created), read the file, and put it on a Notify as you can see:`

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(root, "Nota.txt");


    //Read text from file
    text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close() ;
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I really don't understand why i get this problem, i even try with

```
getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

but without success.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you set permissions in the manifest?

Comment: Check the return value of mkdirs() and do not continue if it returns false. It might not have created the directory.

Comment: Which Android version? 6?

Comment: I have permissions in manifest of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
My version is 5.0, now i try to check the mkdirs()

Comment: EDIT: It creates the directory with mkdirs(), it returns me true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Problem Solved**

I used [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) of Android.
I stored the data in MainActivity and take in in my Class as follow:

- MainActivity

  ```
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  editor.putString("string_id", InputString); //InputString: from the EditText
  editor.commit();
  ```
- In my Class to get my data

  ```
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String data = prefs.getString("string_id", "no id"); //no id: default value
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You've tried to check with a debugger if root exists when you do:

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
if (!root.exists()) {
    root.mkdirs();
}
```

I do not think it will create the folder when you write the file

Answer (score 0):

To write a file in external storage, 
you need to have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission enabled.

Why are you trying to write a file in external storage?

I mean if you want this file for your app only means, use context.getExternalDirs() to get your app's sandbox, it doesn't require write permission, above android 4.2(Jelly bean).

If you want to share the file to other apps, you're doing the right job.

And before writing the file, check whether external storage is mounted programmatically.

Comment: I have to save a memo in the app, which will be showed in a Notify when the app discover a specific bluetooth device (Beacon).

How does context.getExternalDirs() works? Where it save the file?

Comment: getExternalDirs() gives the path specified only to your app, 
it looks like this **Android/Data/<your_packagename>/files/**

this dir is specified to your app only and your app only can write inside this path and it's cleared when app uninstalled.

Though other apps can see the files in it, say File Explorer.
This dir is in SDcard if you have one, if not this is found in your device's Internal storage.
context.getExternalDirs() gives the exact location of your app's sandbox, it may be SDcard or Internal storage.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
Check this link for storage.

ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, directoryType)
Use this method for backward compatibility, it returns array of files,
get the first item returned and proceed also handle null check.

For more detail check this link 
https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html